# Create a list of lengths

Tags: r

I have a list `'T_1'`, where each element is a list of numbers.

I can get the `length` of the first element by

```
length(T_1[[1]])
```

as I understood.

Is it possible to create a new list of lengths of all elements from T_1 without a for loop?
And if not how to do it with a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lapply(T_1, length)
```

will do the trick.

Comment: perfect, thanks. So basically I can apply any function to list by lapply?

Comment: even custom functions, ev.vi!